# Android Activity and Fragment Lifecycle after Permission Revoked in M

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to get my head around the App and its components lifecycles during permisison changes.

Given:

```
  targetSdk = 23
  compileSdk = 23
```

Assume I have my App Open with a Fragment being displayed, and got to settings and revoke a permission.

My understanding is that the process is restarted, however none of the Fragments lifecycle methods are called (onCreateView etc...), and this causes   My test harness application to run into a crash when returning to the app.

I touch a button on the fragment after returning from revoking the permission and:

```
'android.os.IBinder android.widget.EditText.getWindowToken()' on a null object reference
```

This code is used to hide the onscreen keyboard if its displayed, and I can remove it if needed, but the question here is why isn't the fragment being re-created if the process is restarted?

Edit:  Did some more logging.  So it looks like the fragment/activity are calling the lifecycle methods, but it seems like the reinitialization is not really complete.

Comment: There should be no difference between your process being terminated due to a permission revocation and your process being terminated for any other reason.

Comment: That sound like you do something else wrong here.

Comment: You mention this is during a test. Is your test holding reference to the `Activity`? Potentially your test could be holding to an activity that was destroyed and does not have a window anymore. On such situation your test harness should be getting a reference to the newly created activity.

Comment: @Kitesurfer yea this was something else, someone else's code =/  they were referencing an object that may or may not exist at recreation time.  Resolved this elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

When you revoke permissions from app settings - Activity restarts and all it's components too.
But in onCreate(...) savedInstanceState doesn't equal to null.

Thus you can use such hack:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   ...
}
```